# Triggering two different animations onClick?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am trying to trigger two different animations by adding and removing two different css classes with two different css animations by using javascript to do so. However, the div does not preserve the previous animated state, and I need it to do so because of how I designed the UI. I am using forwards in the animations property, but the div performs the animation when it is clicked and then goes back to previous state and then performs the other animation.

```js
const projects = document.getElementById('projects')

projects.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(projects.classList.contains('projects-animation') == true){
        projects.classList.remove('projects-animation')
        projects.classList.add('projects-animation2')
    }
    else{
        console.log('animation2')
        console.log(projects.classList)
        projects.classList.remove('projects-animation2')
        projects.classList.add('projects-animation')
    }
})
```

```css
.projects-container{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: projects;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 100px;
    background-color: hsl(4, 7%, 45%);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.projects{
    position: relative;
    height: fit-content;
}

.projects-animation{
    animation: projects 1s ease-in-out backwards;
}

.projects-animation2{
    animation: projects2 1s ease-in-out backwards;
}

@keyframes projects {
    100%{
        transform: translate(50%,-250%);
    }
}

@keyframes projects2 {
    100%{
        transform: translate(-50%, 250%);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="projects-container">
     <div id = "projects" class="projects">Projects</div>
</div>
```

Comment: just put a comma between the two values

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one,

1: You need to add **0%** as starting point for the second animation,
2: I have used smaller value as larger value moving the child div out of view port, if you want to keep the values then make the parent div large or position it accordingly

```js
    const projects = document.getElementById('projects')

    projects.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(projects.classList.contains('projects-animation') == true){
            projects.classList.remove('projects-animation')
            projects.classList.add('projects-animation2')
        }
        else{
            console.log('animation2')
            console.log(projects.classList)
            projects.classList.remove('projects-animation2')
            projects.classList.add('projects-animation')
        }
    })
```

```css
    .projects-container{
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        grid-area: projects;
        padding: 20px;
        font-size: 100px;
        background-color: hsl(4, 7%, 45%);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .projects{
        position: relative;
        height: fit-content;
    }

    .projects-animation{
        animation: projects 1s ease-in-out forwards;
    }

    .projects-animation2{
        animation: projects2 1s ease-in-out forwards;
    }

    @keyframes projects {
        100%{
            transform: translate(10%,-10%);
        }
    }

    @keyframes projects2 {
        0%{
            transform: translate(10%,-10%);
        }
        100%{
            transform: translate(0%, 0%);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="projects-container">
         <div id = "projects" class="projects">Projects</div>
    </div>
```